# complex canvas getting stuck in the middle

Tags: celery, celery-task

**Setup:**
Celery 4.1.0, broker=RabbitMQ 3.6.5, backend=Redis 3.2.5

Consider the following canvas:

`celery worker -A worker.celeryapp:app -l info -Q default -c 2 -n defaultworker@%h -Ofair`

```
@app.task(name='task_1',
          bind=True,
          base=MyConnectionHolderTask)
def task_1(self, feed_id, flow_id, **kwargs):
    do_something()

task_1 = t_1.si(feed_id, flow_id)
  .
  .
task_13 = t_13.si(feed_id, flow_id)


       (task_1 |
        group((task_2 | group(task_3, task_4)),
              task_5,
              task_6,
              task_7,
              task_8) |
        task_9 |
        task_10 |
        task_11 |
        task_12 |
        task_13).apply_async(link_error=unlock)
```

means I have chain of tasks which one of its tasks is a group of several tasks, and one of them is chain of size 2 (with latter task as group of 2).

### Expected behavior

all task succeeded so expecting finish until task_13

### Actual behavior

task_4 is the last to run. task_9 and the rest (10..13) doesn't run.
if i cancel the group of task_3 & task_4 it does work (till 13):

```
       (task_1 |
        group((task_2 | task_3 | task_4),
              task_5,
              task_6,
              task_7,
              task_8) |
        task_9 |
        task_10 |
        task_11 |
        task_12 |
        task_13).apply_async(link_error=unlock)
```

Ref: [Issue in github](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4164)